# Where is the top level module in python import tree? How to define it?

Tags: python, python-import

I have been working on a project that involves multiple files and have been having some issues with imports. I have read about 20 articles and stack overflow questions, but none seems to explain this behavior.

If I have a folder system that looks like this:

```
\package
    \folder_a
        __init__.py
        b.py
    __init__.py
    a.py
```

with a simple `hello` function in `b.py`. In `a.py` I have `from package.folder_a.b import hello`. When I run `a.py`, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'package'".

Why does this  happen? When `a.py` is run, isn't `package` the top level directory?

Now, I have found a fix for this by simply changing the code in `a.py` to `from folder_a.b import hello`, but this comes with it another set of issues. let us say that I am working with a slightly more complicated file structure(witch I am) such as:

```
\package
    \folder_a
        __init__.py
        b.py
    \folder_b
        __init__.py
        c.py
    __init__.py
    a.py
```

Here I want to import `hello` into `c.py`. BOTH `from package.folder_a.b import hello` AND `from folder_a.b import hello` reult in the same "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'package/folder_a(repectivly)'". I presume that this is because the file does not add thoes folders to the namespace when the file is executed (importing c into a when running a.py allows the import to work). Is there any way to force `\package` to be the top level module that does not involve running a script from a file in it's own directory? I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/11082165)

Comment: Yes, but both of the solutions offered there are not applicable

Comment: Your fix makes it so that `package` isn't actually a package, but a directory containing two top-level packages named `folder_a` and `folder_b`. In general, don't store files intended as scripts inside folders intended to be interpreted as packages.

Comment: I think one of the problems I have is that eventually I want this project to become a package that I can distribute on PyPI, so package has to be a module. @chepner: Thanks, do you think that putting all of the files that will actually run something (and eventually act as entry points) inside the top level directory will fix it. At that point the top level directory should be available in the name space, but I am concerned about under-pathing (not referencing the `\package` when it becomes available.

Comment: The question is, do you ever plan on *importing* `a` from another script? If yes, then we need to modify `a` to work as both a module and a script. If not, then you shouldn't treat `package` as a package at all.

Comment: @chepner: 'a' is essentially a main file that only acts as an entry point for my app by importing and executing high level functions.

Comment: Ok, then `package` is *just* a directory, not actually a package containing subpackages `folder_a` and `folder_b`.

Comment: @chepner: I am very sorry, but I was mistaken before. `a` will need to be imported into other files, just not files within that directory. For example, after I install this package using pip I might run a main function in `a` from another file. So as you said, it will have to be both.

Comment: Like a linux binary or a windows executable, python distinguishes between the top script being executed and the packages/modules it can import (the latter being like .so or .dll files in those platforms). Top level scripts are not part of any package. So, its important to know how you run a.py. Is it a top level script or is it imported from some other script (or python shell?).

Comment: I would consider refactoring `a.py` into a standalone script and a module that it imports `a.py`, but that's mainly so I don't need to rewrite half my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's rename `package` to avoid confusion, because the intent is not to define a package containing a module named `a`. You have a *project* that defines three things:

1. A top-level package that contains a module named `b`
2. A top-level package that contains a module named `c`
3. A *script* named `a.py`.

or you might define two things:

1. A top-level package `package` that contains two sub packages `p1` and `p2`
2. A script named `a.py`.

So your *source* directory might look like

```
\project
    \p1
        b.py
    \p2
        c.py
    a.py
```

or

```
\project
    \package
        \p1
            b.py
        \p2
            c.py
    a.py
```

(Unless you actually have code to put in the `__init__.py` files, they haven't been necessary to define a package for a long time.)

When you install the code from a *distribution package* (say, with `pip install myproject` into a virtual environment), then `a.py` will go to an appropriate `bin` directory and the two packages `p1` and `p2` to an appropriate `site-packages` directory. For example, assuming the first alternative above,

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ venv/pip/install myproject
[...]
$ ls venv/bin/a.py
venv/bin/a.py
$ ls -d venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/p*
venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/p1
venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/p1
```

So `a.py` should refer to `p1` and `p2` as top-level packages, for example with

```
from p1 import b
from p2 import c
```

not with relative imports as if `a` were a module in the same package as `p1` and `p2`. If you opt for the second alternative,

```
from package.p1 import b
from package.p2 import c
```

---

If you *do* want `a.py` to be a module that can also be run as a script, then your source tree might look like

```
\project
    \package
        \p1
            b.py
        \p2
            c.py
        a.py
```

Now `package.a` is a module, along with `package.p1` and `package.p2`, and `a.py` can use relative imports to refer to `p1` and `p2`. To ensure that relative imports work when `a.py` is executed as a script as well, then add the following boilerplate before the first relative import:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = 'package'
```

Comment: @Wills There are more options than I want to cover, so could you pick whether I should describe 1) Three top-level modules `p1`, `p2`, and `a`, 2) A top-level package `package` that contains `p1`, `p2`, and `a`, or 3) A top-level package `package` containing `p1` and `p2` and a top-level module `a`. (In all three scenarios, `a` can be run as a script as well.)

Comment: Thanks for all this help. Explaining the pip was very instructive. I am going with the first option where `a` is in the same directory as the folders. I am doing what I believe is recommended for packages with a `src` folder, then `package` then scripts and modules. (https://github.com/GillsSpace/Backgammon_AI if you want to see what I actually have for structure (I hope that is allowed)). I have taken the time to re-factor, but am getting an error with not finding the folders. I think the problem may lie in that the `site-packages` folder you talked about ....

Comment: ...only has the main `package` folder instead of `p1` and `p2` (thought the package folder has them inside of course). Not sure how to fix this though.

Answer (score 0):

Python treats the directory where the script being executed resides as the top level directory, as an example when executing b.py in directory folder_b, /folder_b would be considered as the top level directory and not the /package.
to tackle your situation, you can use relative imports. Here's how you can adjust your imports in a.py and c.py:

file a.py ->
from .folder_a.b import hello

file c.py ->
from ..folder_a.b import hello

This allows Python to correctly resolve the module paths regardless of the current working directory or the location of the script being executed.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the most succinct and least confusing explanation of relative imports I have seen.

Comment: If `a.py` is intended to be a script, it should not be using relative imports to refer to `folder_a`, because `a.py` does not define a module in *any* package.

Comment: @wills - did you run this? Did it work?